# How to delete a secret key/password from a new fork?

Tags: git

I have a repo on GitHub that I want to open source. Before I do, I want to fork the private project, remove my secret API keys from the app, and then release the fork as open source.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the `git filter-branch` command to rewrite history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: What's Rakefile you have in there in the command? And how is that related with the OP's question?

Comment: @t0mm13b: That's a sample filename.  The OP can use this command to destroy all history of the file with the secret key.

Comment: I would have called it YOUR_FILE... I ended up googling and found this same chunk of text here: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Comment: @AndrewJohnson: That's what I linked to.